# Wordpress website title not removing from tab

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have changed the name from setting but it's still showing on the tab in a browser when I view any page. However I have cleared the cache. it's on a Localhost

Comment: Wait 30 minutes. Reload. Sometimes you've just *got* to be patient.

Comment: yes it's on a localhost

Comment: How long it can take?

Comment: try incognito tab

Answer (score 1):

If it is a custom WordPress theme then please check header.php, in that check for  tag, you must have hardcoded the title.